# Dropzone Bootstrap JS Error

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Heyho -

i am not the best in javascript. I tried to get Dropzone Bootstrap ( http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html ) to work but i am getting an error in my console.

This is the error: http://postimg.org/image/f1fx0cz1j/

I can see the Bootstrap theme for a milli secound but then im getting the default theme.

The Form has the Class dropzone.

I just copy and pasted the code from the above given link, so there should actually nothing be wrong.

Comment: Just want to know..Have your inserted Dropzone.js ? it may happen that you have forgot file to add..

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems with the sample code.

Could it be, that you just copied the visible sample code from the page and did not include **dropzone.js** in your html header or at the end of your body?

If you want to copy the sample, you actually need to copy the whole page - so you could save it local or view html source and copy paste it. The code snippets shown on the page itself are just for explanation but do not run on their own.

So make sure you have some sort of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dropzone.js"></script>
```

either in your html head or before your last `</body>` tag

Comment: I did included dropzone.js. But the complete code is hidden in the html code instead of


<div class="table table-striped" id="previews"></div>

Comment: definably your error shows, that Dropzone is not defined. maybe you should start of with an empty html page, copy the dropzone.js include in there and then just one line of js to create the Dropzone object to test. Or better start off with the simple sample from dropzone homepage